# Right tools to make a GUI / web interface app

Tags: python, web-applications, websocket, youtube-api

What I want to create is a music player that can interact with YouTube using its Data API.

I actually have already developed my application (only for Windows, multi-platform is not a priority at the moment) using AutoIt and it's working properly. For now I createad a GUI to simply execute [mpv.io](https://mpv.io/), send commands to it and get its STDOUT to manage informations/errors.

Now I wanted to create a web interface to control this application using my smartphone in particular. I tried to look into TCP implementation and also WebSockets to send real time information like the playback position, but I'm not too sure what to look into.

As you probably can understand, I don't have much experience especially in network stuff so a help would be much appreciated. In the past I've fiddled with HTML,CSS,JavaScript so the web interface should not be a problem but for the communication part I don't have many ideas.

Since I created some very basic application with Python in the past, someone already suggested me to use a web framework like Flask, and so I started to properly learn Python but I find difficulties with GUIs...

So, to do a little summary I'm currently asking what can be a proper method to develop this application, also starting from scratch and changing programming language, since I'm always open to learn something new.